# to write inner join in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have three class User, Department and Designation

**User.java**

```
public class User implements Serializable{  
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name="emailId")
    private String emailId;

    @Column(name="userName")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name="mobNo")
    private BigDecimal mobNo;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "deptId")
    private Department department;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "desgId")
    private Designation designation;

    @Column(name="grpId")
    private int grpId ;

    @Column(name="userLevel")
    private int userLevel ;

    @Column(name="upw1")
    private String upw1 ;

    @Column(name="upw2")
    private String upw2 ;

    @Column(name="upw3")
    private String upw3 ;

    @Column(name="createdBy")
    private String createdBy ;

    @Column(name="creationDate")
    private Timestamp creationDate;

    @Column(name="loginStatus")
    private String loginStatus;

    @Column(name="hintId")
    private int hintId ;

    @Column(name="hintAns")
    private String hintAns ;

    @Column(name="otp")
    private String otp ;
}
```

**Department.java**

```
public class Department implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int deptid;

    @Column(name="deptnm")
    private String deptnm;

    @Column(name="shrtnm")
    private String shrtnm;

    @Column(name="creationdt")
    private Timestamp creationdt;

    @Column(name="status")
    private String status;
}
```

**Designation.java**

```
public class Designation implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int desgid;

    @Column(name="desgnm")
    private String desgnm;

    @Column(name="shrtnm")
    private String shrtnm;

    @Column(name="creationdt")
    private Timestamp creationdt;

    @Column(name="status")
    private String status;

    public Designation() {
    }
}
```

**SQL**

```
select u.username, u.mobno, dp.deptnm, ds.desgnm, u.loginstatus from  usermst u
    inner join  deptmst dp ON u.deptid=dp.deptid 
    INNER JOIN  desigmst ds on u.desgid=ds.desgid
```

I want to write query on it as 
How to write this sql query in hibernate?
I tried by criteria, hql but did not work

Comment: JOIN variables are represented in criteria queries by the Join interface (and its sub interfaces).

For example, the following JPQL query:

`SELECT c, p.name FROM Country c LEFT OUTER JOIN c.capital p`
can be built as a criteria query using the following code:

 `CriteriaQuery<Country> q = cb.createQuery(Country.class);
  Root<Country> c = q.from(Country.class);
  Join<Country> p = c.join("capital", JoinType.LEFT);
  q.multiselect(c, p.get("name"));`

Reference: https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you don't really need an hql join, you can just navigate through the department and designation associations. Try this if you really want the result as a collections of array

```
select
    u.username, u.mobno, u.department.deptnm, u.designation.desgnm, u.loginstatus
from
    User u
```

to use such query

```
Query query=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select u.userName, u.mobNo, u.department.deptnm, u.designation.desgnm, " + "u.loginStatus from User u");
List<Object[]> list=query.list();
```

but if you just want to get a list of user

```
Query query=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User u");
List<User> list=query.list();
```

Comment: I am trying this but i got the exception is as   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "userName"

Comment: you should select from `User` (select u.userName, u.mobNo, u.loginStatus, u.department.deptnm, u.designation.desgnm  from User u). @JyotiJadhav are you converting the values at some point?

Comment: this is my query (select u.userName, u.mobNo, u.department.deptnm, u.designation.desgnm, u.loginStatus from User u)

Comment: I got ClassCastException and my method is  (public List<User> getUsers(){
  Query query=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
       .createQuery("select u.userName, u.mobNo, u.department.deptnm, u.designation.desgnm, "
         + "u.loginStatus from User u");
  List<User> list=(List<User>)query.list();
  return list;
})

Comment: Thank you @gtosto

Answer (score 0):

are you try this way?

```
  String query = "select u.username, u.mobno, 
  u.loginstatus, dp.deptnm, ds.desgnm  from  USERMST 
  u, DEPTMST dp, DESIGMST ds where 
  u.deptid=dp.deptid and u.desgid=ds.desgid";

  SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(query);
```

query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);

```
  List data = query.list();

  for (Object object : data) {
     Map row = (Map) object;
     sysout(row.get("username"));
     //similar-way all the values

  }
```